# Connect to Java socket via hostname

Tags: java, flash, websocket, cloud9

Is it possible to connect to Java WebSocket through flash using server hostname, not IP? The reason is the specifications of Cloud9, they don't give any IPs, only hostnames. Tests showed that WebSocket gets requests to connect through browser, but not from Socket class in Flash

Comment: Did you check the docs?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I connect to remote host by hostname (e.g. something.cloud9.io), it logs nothing which means it didn't get the request

Answer (score 2):

programming for a Client:

```
Socket MyClient;
try {
       MyClient = new Socket("Machine name", PortNumber);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

programming for a Server:

```
ServerSocket MyService;
try {
   MyServerice = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
```

for further you can refer below URL :-

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html